# get value from label dynamically created using jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

here my jsp code

```
    <%
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    %>
    <div style="height: 100px;width: 200px;border:1px dotted red;">
        <label id="nc<%=i%>" hidden=""><%=i%></label>
        <button type="button" onclick="validate1('<%=i%>')">Post</button>
    </div>

    <%            }
    %>
```

and this java script

```
      <script>


        function validate1(i)
        {
            alert(i);
            var value = $("#nc"+i).text();
            alert("Label value= " + value);
        }
    </script>
```

here i am unable get the label value which is created by dynamically using for loop
please help me out...

Comment: do you get any error in the console??

Comment: no but i m not getting second alert...

Comment: I suspect you are calling this function before jquery is loaded. To rule out this, try retrieving the value by document.getElementById("nc" + i).innerHTML

Comment: well use browser console to see js errors.and check html source

Comment: why cant i use jquery?

Comment: You can use jquery, but you need to make sure your jquery js is loaded and then you are using its selectors and functions

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `children` to do this and change the `validate1` to receive the button:

```
<div style="height: 100px;width: 200px;border:1px dotted red;">
    <label id="nc<%=i%>" hidden=""><%=i%></label>
    <button type="button" onclick="validate1(this)">Post</button>
</div>
```

And the function:

```
function validate1(button)
    {
        var value = $(button).parent().children("label").text();
        alert("Label value= " + value);
    }
```

If you wanna the label id you can do:

```
var id = $(button).parent().children("label").attr("id");
```